# PHP - Obter valores de variáveis em string

Tags: php, wordpress, string, youtube-api

Sou novo em Wordpress e PHP e estou com um probleminha rsrs

Tenho uma string bem grande que obtenho dinamicamente. Essa string é, na verdade, um array com vários valores e variáveis. Gostaria de pegar todos os valores contidos na variável videoID que se repete N vezes dentro desse array (que na verdade é uma string).

Ou, em outras palavras, estou tentando usar a API do YouTube para mostrar o conteúdo de uma playlist no meu site. Consegui apenas obter uma string GIGANTE usando *file_get_contents* na url *https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&maxResults=50&playlistId=ID_DA_PLAYLIST&key=API_KEY* . Se alguém puder me ajudar a fazer isso :)

Obrigado!

Comment: Não pode codificar o array em json pra facilitar a transferência, e usar um foreach para obter os ids em uma nova variável?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Criei uma API_KEY pra responder sua pergunta. :)

O objeto json que a API do Youtube envia é grandinho e tem um monte de detalhes, se quiser montar um array só com os ids dos vídeos, pode fazer o seguinte:

```
<?php

$playlist = "SUA_ID_DA_PLAYLIST";
$api_key = "SUA_API_KEY";

// URL com ID da API e da lista de reprodução
$url_do_youtube = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&maxResults=50&playlistId=".$playlist."&key=".$api_key;

$json = file_get_contents($url_do_youtube);

$obj_videos = json_decode($json);

//var_dump($obj_videos);

$lista_videos = $obj_videos->items;

$lista_id_videos = array();

foreach($lista_videos as $obj_video)
{
    $lista_id_videos[] = $obj_video->contentDetails->videoId;
}


var_dump($lista_id_videos);
```

Espero que ajude, se tiver alguma dúvida pergunte aqui mesmo.
Se a resposta tiver sido útil, dê uma moral e aceite como resposta e clique na setinha pra cima pra me dar pontos de reputação. Falow, valew. :)

Comment: car****!!!! valeu amigo!!! funcionou perfeitamente como eu precisava :D kkk... eu sou novo como "questionador" aqui no Stackoverflow (foi minha primeira pergunta kkk), estou clicando na setinha pra cima mas n está incrementando o 0 :s... mas marquei como resposta kkk

novamente MUITO obrigado pela ajuda :D :D

Comment: Que bom! 
Valew meu camarada! 
Boa sorte aí com seu projeto. Abraços. :)

Comment: @RBFraphael logo que vc tiver mais pontos poderá votar nas questões e respostas, suas e de terceiros.